# How to show the razorpay checkout amount in firebase flutter?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, integration, razorpay

I have an issue in my app.I have using razorpay for the payment gateway,the payment is success,and that is showing in the razorpay web, but I want to show the corresponding payment of the user in the firebase.Im doing a Elearning app.And my primary goal is ,while a user authenticating the firebase must show the user is paided member or not.when the user user is a premiere member ,the firebase database shows the user is paided member.I watched so many videos but I didn't get the solutions for it.[image]

Comment: Its dependent on how you deal it. On User Model you need to have some sort of flag or type of user and after users payment is success on that function you need to update that user's type as paid.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)